# What is grammatically correct and why

Tags: american-english, definite-articles, compliment

While complimenting someone, what is correct to say -

- You have **an amazing** taste, or
- You have **amazing** taste.

I checked on online grammar checking websites, they consider both sentences as correct. I am confused about when to use or not use **an** with amazing here.

Comment: Food has an amazing taste. People have good taste, or amazing taste, unless we mean kisses sweeter than wine.

Answer (score 1):

“You have amazing taste” is correct. But: watch out for an occasional qualifier. “She has an amazing taste for bourbon”.